# Convert multiple securiy http configuration from xml to java configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cas, spring-java-config

I have multiple `security:http` configurations in my xml with different entry-point-ref. I am trying to convert this config to java config.

I have read that this is possible using multiple sub classes extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

How should I configure the entry-point-ref for each of these in java config?

follwing is the xml config.

```
<security:http request-matcher-ref="preReqMatcher" auto-config="false" use-expressions="false" entry-point-    ref="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthFilter" />
    <custom-filter after="CAS_FILTER" ref="attrFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />  
    <csrf disabled="true"/> 
</security:http> 

<security:http auto-config="true" entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint" use-expressions="false" disable-url-rewriting="false">
    <custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casFilter" />
    <custom-filter after="CAS_FILTER" ref="attrFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <custom-filter ref="testFilter" before="CAS_FILTER" />
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</security:http>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the way I figured out to configure the entry-point.

`http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint);`

Answer (score 0):

Configuration of security with Java classes start by providing your @Configuration classes subclassing org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter for the "web" part (request) and org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration for the "global" part (service layer).

In the sub-class of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, you have to override some "configure(...)" methods: (just examples...)

```
public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            //  @formatter:off
            web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/*.html","/*.ico","/css/**","/html/**","/i18n/**","/img/**","/js/**","/lib/**");
            //  @formatter:on
}

protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

http.headers()
                .addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN))
                .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .addFilterAfter(jeePreAuthenticatedFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
                    .addFilterBefore(new BasicAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean()),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .addFilterBefore(switchUserProcessingFilter(), SwitchUserFilter.class)
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/*.html","/*.ico","/css/**","/html/**","/i18n/**","/img/**","/js/**","/lib/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()

                .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionFixation().none().maximumSessions(maxSessionsPerUser)
                    .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry)
                ;

}

protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(basicDAOAuthenticationProvider());
    auth.authenticationProvider(preauthAuthProvider());
}
```

In that @Configuration class, you should/could also have beans for the MethodSecurityMetadataSource, AccessDecisionManager, AccessDecisionVoter, ... your authentication providers, ...

Same principle your @Configuration, sub-class of GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration:

```
protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
...
}

protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
...
}

protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
    ...;
}


@Bean
public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
...
}
```